# Django - last insert id

Tags: python, django

I can't get the last insert id like I usually do and I'm not sure why.

In my view:

```
comment = Comments( ...)
comment.save()
comment.id #returns None
```

In my Model:

```
class Comments(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
```

Has anyone run into this problem before?  Usually after I call the save() method, I have access to the id via comment.id, but this time it's not working.

Comment: Do you ever set the id? You're not using an AutoField.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you setting the value of the `id` field in the `comment = Comments( ...)`
 line?  If not, why are you defining the field instead of just letting Django take care of the primary key with an AutoField?

If you specify in IntegerField as a primary key as you're doing in the example Django won't automatically assign it a value.

Comment: no, I don't define id it's auto incremented.  I didn't realize that, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Simply do

```
c = Comment.object.latest()
```

That should return you the last inserted comment

```
c.pk

12 #last comment saved.
```

Comment: That should be `objects`, not `object`.

Answer (score 2):

To define an automatically set primary key use AutoField:

```
class Comments(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to specifically set a new IntegerField called id as the primary key? Because Django already does that for you for free...

That being said, have you tried removing the id field from your comment model?