# Concept of Foreign Key

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have two models let say A and B.

A is one to one with auth_user and B is related to A via Foreign Key.

Now when I try to feed the data in model B it gives me an error of **A_id' cannot be null**. So can anybody tell me how can I feed the data to foreign key OR it can by default got the id of model A if yes then how???

**NOTE:**

I used the separate form for each model, means I am submitting the data in model A and after success it refer me to the profile page and then where I click on link to fill the details of second model and therefore second form comes into play.
So here I don't know how that foreign  key gets the id of model A.

Comment: If you can't to add data to the model B without having corresponding record on model A, and but you want to, then your design is not good. Otherwise follow the llian's answer...

Comment: I have data in model A , if I complete the details of model then only I can see the profile and hence link

Comment: If so you can query the last inserted row id from the model A. What are the languages that you are using ?

Comment: i don't know python or Django, but try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161149/django-last-insert-id) SO question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create you B object you need to provide a reference to an A object.

You say you're using a form to create the B object so you'll probably need something along the lines of...

```
b_instance = new_b_form.save(commit=False)
b_instance.a = A.objects.get(something="whatever")  # You'll know how to find the A object you want related.
b_instance.save()
```

Setting a will automatically set a_id to be saved in the database.

Alternatively you may be able to change your form so that the user can select the A object.

Answer (score 1):

You should allow the model B FK field to be empty (null=True, blank=True) if you want to save it without reference to model A i.e. if FK is Null.
Otherwise you will have to feed the B object with A object and then to save it.

Comment: I can get the objects of A in this way X=A.objects.all() 
so what should i write When i am submitting the data in to B so that B's foreign key get the A's primery key

Comment: In brief:
obj_a = A.objects.get(<filter_here>) # beware get can throw exception \n

B.fk_to_a_field = obj_a \n

B.save()